# proxyquire Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sequelize.js, sinon, proxyquire

Hello I am new to testing with `mocha/chai/sinon and sequelize-test-helpers`

Trying to use `proxyquire` to override the `require` but having issues

Getting this following error about the path:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:<local-directories-path>\ecommerce-pern-app\server\src\models'
```

I dont get why there is a `src folder` when I don't have a `src folder` at all I am using the `proxyquire` in the test file and its path is from the `server` directory would be:

server/specs/services/user-service.spec.js

```
"use strict";
const chai = require('chai');
const {match, stub, resetHistory, spy} = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const path = require('path');
const service = path.resolve('./services/userService.js')
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);

console.log(service)

const {makeMockModels, sequelize, dataTypes,} = require('sequelize-test-helpers');

describe('Idea Controller', function () {

  const uid = '6a88e9b5-33a2-403f-ac3d-e86413ac101d'
  const data = {
    email: 'testface@test.com',
    password: '123456',
    is_admin: false,
    first_name: 'Testy',
    last_name: 'McTestface', 
    google_id: null,
    facebook_id: null
  }

    describe('findAll()', function () {
        it('Success case ', function () {

            const mockResponse = () => {
                const res = {};
                res.json = stub().returns(res);
                return res;
            };

            let res = mockResponse();

            const User = {findAll: stub()};
            const mockModels = makeMockModels({User});

            Idea.findAll.resolves(data);

            const UserService = proxyquire(service, {
              "save": {}
            });

            UserService.findAll({}, res);

            Idea.findAll.should.have.been.called; // passes
            res.json.should.have.been.called; //fails
        });
    })
});
```

In the above code I am using the proxyquire like this:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const path = require('path');
const service = path.resolve('./services/userService.js')
const {makeMockModel} = require('sequelize-test-helpers');

            const mockModels = makeMockModels({User});

            const UserService = proxyquire(service, {
              "../models": mockModels
            });
```

As I am trying to use the path to find the `server/service/userService.js` file which is relatively located from the test file at `../../services/userService.js`. I have got this bug that there is `src folder` there when I do not have a `src directory` at all even!

As the bug is saying:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:<local-directories-path>\ecommerce-pern-app\server\src\models'
```

Whatever I try about file path is not working I tried path.resolve, path.join and directly typing the path into it as like `../../services/userService.js`

here is the
server/services/userService.js

```
const Models = require('../models');
const { User } = Models;

const save = async ({ id, ...data }) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { uid: id } })
  if (user) return await user.update(data)
  return null
}


module.exports = save;
```

I just want the path to with proxyquire to work

What is this \src\models path from the error, I dont have a src/models path route at all!

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from [sequelize-test-helpers's readme](https://github.com/davesag/sequelize-test-helpers).

> As a convenience, makeMockModels will automatically populate your mockModels with mocks of all of the models defined in your [src/models folder](https://github.com/davesag/sequelize-test-helpers/blob/9b287d21ea65fdc219600dc94c3f69712c68ff69/src/mockModels.js#L20) (or if you have a .sequelizerc file it will look for the models-path in that). Simply override any of the specific models you need to do stuff with.

So you need to provide .sequelizerc file and define `models-path`.